# Trend Micro SysClean.com needs da5 but I can only find da6

Tags: anti-virus, anti-spyware

The Trend Micro command line scanner [SysClean](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/Pages/Does-Trend-Micro-have-a-command-line-antivirus-scanner.aspx) apparently needs an up-to-date definition file for spyware that ends in da5.  However, the download list from Trend Micro only has a definition file ending in da6.  How do I get SysClean to use the latest da6 file definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all you have to do is download the file with a .da6 extension and rename it to a .da5 extension.  I'll post more if I find that not to be the case.